# Configure ESLint to error when objects are defined with certain keys

Tags: eslint

I know of the [no-restricted-properties](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-properties) option that allows setting up rules to error when *accessing* certain object keys (to discourage use of deprecated APIs and the like), but I cannot find a rule to disallow *setting* of certain keys.

Is this possible in ESLint?

To explain further, our project uses [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) ORM which uses the keyword `allowNull` for nullable columns, and we often copy our Sequelize model definitions directly into [node-pg-migrate](https://github.com/salsita/node-pg-migrate) migration files, which uses the subtly different `notNull` keyword.

I always forget to change the object key in a definition from `allowNull` to `notNull` and would like a way to check this in the linter in a directory specific `.eslintrc` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the similarly named [no-restricted-syntax](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax) rule allows you to exclude pretty much anything you can find using Javascript AST selectors. Using the very helpful [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/) web tool, I was able to add a `.eslintrc` file in the directory with our database migrations with a single rule to error when objects have the key `allowNull`:

```
{
 "rules": {
    "no-restricted-syntax": [
      "error", "Identifier[name='allowNull']",
    ]
  }
}
```